# Webhook for twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter, webhooks

I'm developing a tweet fetcher for a ruby on rails application and I want to user the official ruby gem for that. I experimented quite a bit and it all works nice. But I'm wondering how can I get a notification when a certain event happens (Anyone retweets, mentions me, uses a hashtag, ...). Are there any webhooks that twitter provides? If not what is best practise to workaround that (User based fetching, automatic request every x minutes, ...)?

Thanks for any directions.

Best regards

Comment: Twitters API has some limitations unless you are willing to pay for it through `firehose` but take a look here [Twitter Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Twitter app for your purpose. Refer dev.twitter.com to get more details.

Through this Twitter app, you can get your required tweet details.

It is bit vague. But the Twitter developer website will give you more details.

This [URL](http://blog.benmorgan.io/post/79339120263/how-to-use-the-twitter-api-for-ruby-on-rails) will help you on accessing Twitter data using Ruby On Rails.

Comment: I appreciate the link to my blog post. I'd actually recommend, if you know how, to make `Twitter` a service object or a concern if you know how. This would make some tasks easy for moving them to jobs and not having to utilize global variables.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for a solution.  I see [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/twitter/webhook/) talking about posting to a webhook on some twitter events.

But it kind of looks like there will be significant latency, on the order of 5 or 15 minutes depending on how much you pay them.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter doesn't have webhooks. You can use the Twitter Streaming API which will be closest to real-time or you can poll the REST API.

Polling can be a pain because of their rate limits, so streaming is your best bet.